# Numerical Methods - Numerical Integration

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am trying to do this question i found on the internet but it has only has answers so no idea how to do it.

[image]

So far we have learnt, Newton Coates, Trapezium and Simpsons (Composite methods of both of these) and Guassian quadrature. However trapezium has DoE =1, Simpsons = 3 and the composites mirroring these, i don't know how to do Gaussian of more than 2 nodes. Any ideas or help?

Comment: The degree of exactness of Gauss-integration is $2n-1$, if $n$ is the number of nodes.

Comment: Note that what Peter just said, although it does *turn out* to be what you have here, is not guaranteed to be what you would get out of this case, because the nodes are not completely free (you have only 4 free variables instead of 6).

Comment: @Peter Yes you are correct but from looking at the RHS there are 3 nodes and at this point in the course we only know how to do 2 nodes

Comment: @SamHarper You can brute force it by seeking to solve the system of equations $A (-\alpha)^k + B 0^k + C \alpha^k = \int_{-1}^1 x^k dx$ for $k=0,1,\dots,4$, where we understand $0^0=1$. Of course by actually developing the theory you can come up with a more efficient procedure, but this procedure does work, and this case is relatively small.

Comment: If you have the formula, to find the degree is easy. Just look which of the expressions $x^n$, $n=0,1,2,\cdots $ are correctly integrated. The largest exponent is the degree of exactness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ian and @Peter described in the comments

There are more efficient procedures but a "brute force" approach works just fine, i have typed up a small example after doing this all one needs to do is simply equate.

[image]

Comment: Your line $\int_{-1}^1x\ dx$ should equal $A(-\alpha)+B(0)+C(\alpha)$ and similarly for the other three.  The left side of this is zero, so you get $\alpha(C-A)=0$. The fourth will be redundant with the second, so you need another line with $x^4$ to have enough information to solve for $A,B,C,\alpha$.  The problem called for exactness through $x^4$